# How to put results in a table using 2D arrays C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to output all of my values in a table similar to the example output shown below. Could anyone tell me how I would go about getting something like this?

[Example Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m01Ie.jpg)

```
string[] salesReps =
{
    "Dave", "Sarah", "Juan", "Gilno",
};

string[] months =
{
    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May",
    "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep",
    "Oct", "Nov", "Dec",
};

int[,] salesStats = new int[4, 12]
{
    { 67, 34, 23, 54, 34, 12, 34, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, },
    { 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, },
    { 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 111, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, },
    { 87, 6, 5, 4, 34, 67, 87, 54, 34, 5, 6, 7, },
};
```

Comment: You'll probably need to loop through the values in each column first, and check their length so that you can space everything correctly. Also, you should probably create an object to hold information that is meant to be grouped together. Working with independent arrays is asking for trouble.

Comment: `Could anyone tell me how I would go about getting something like this with the code I already have` can you change the code you already have, if so, I would encourage a different direction than the path you're going.

Comment: Yes I can still edit my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works nicely:

```
int maxSalesRep = salesReps.Max(x => x.Length);
int maxData = months.Max(x => x.Length);

foreach (var stat in salesStats.Cast<int>())
{
    var text = stat.ToString();
    if (text.Length > maxData)
    {
        maxData = text.Length;
    }
}

Console.Write("".PadLeft(maxSalesRep));
Console.Write(" ");
Console.WriteLine(
    String.Join(
        " ",
        months.Select(x => x.PadLeft(maxData))));

for (int i = 0; i < salesReps.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write(salesReps[i].PadLeft(maxSalesRep));
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.WriteLine(
        String.Join(
            " ",
            Enumerable.Range(0, months.Length).Select(j => $"{salesStats[i, j]}".PadLeft(maxData))));
}
```

That gives me:

```
      Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
 Dave  67  34  23  54  34  12  34   2   3   4   5   6
Sarah   7   6   5   4   3   3   2   1   2   3   4   5
 Juan   6   7   8   9   0 111  12  13  14  15  16  17
Gilno  87   6   5   4  34  67  87  54  34   5   6   7
```

Or perhaps slightly better:

```
IEnumerable<string> lines =
        Enumerable
            .Range(0, salesReps.Length)
            .Select(i => Enumerable.Range(0, months.Length).Select(j => salesStats[i, j].ToString().PadLeft(maxData)).StartWith(salesReps[i].PadLeft(maxSalesRep)))
            .StartWith(months.Select(m => m.PadLeft(maxData)).StartWith("".PadLeft(maxSalesRep)))
            .Select(x => String.Join(" ", x));

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to it with a for loop

```
Console.Write("\t");
for (int i = 0; i< months.Length; i++)  //print header
{ 
    Console.Write(months[i] + "\t");
}
Console.WriteLine();

for (int i = 0; i < salesReps.Length; i++) //for each sales rep
{
    Console.Write(salesReps[i] + "\t"); //prints name
    for (int j = 0; j < salesStats.GetLength(1); j++) //for each month
        {
            Console.Write(salesStats[i, j] + "\t"); //prints values
        }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Gives you this:
[image]